# Acumatica Showing Weekly Instead of Daily, Monthly, or Yearly

Tags: acumatica

I am working on a GI in Acumatica that shows returns for the year by day and or by month, but I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish by showing returns by each week to get a weekly percentage.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that using Pivot Tables by setting "Round to" property (week, two weeks, month, quarter, etc.).
Could you please share your inquiry in XML format so I can take a look on it?